# Deriving the sum to product formula for sine using this method

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to derive $sinC-sinD$ By this method:

[image]

So far I have tried to set up the same method by beginning with $sin(A+B)-sin(A-B)$, but this reduces to a trivial zero and I can't find another way to approach it without using the product to sum formulas.

(NOTE: I am trying to avoid using the product to sum formulas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$ \begin{aligned} & \sin(A+B) = \sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B \\ & \sin(A-B) = \sin A \cos B - \cos A \sin B \end{aligned} \implies \sin(A+B) - \sin(A-B) = 2\cos A \sin B $$
>
> > $$ \begin{aligned} & A := \dfrac{C+D}{2} \\ & B := \dfrac{C-D}{2} \end{aligned} \ \implies \sin C - \sin D = 2\cos \left( \dfrac{C+D}{2} \right) \sin \left( \dfrac{C-D}{2} \right)$$

Comment: I used the sum to product formulae. Does that count as not the 'product to sum' formulae?

Comment: Wait I did the exact same thing as you instead for the $sin(A+b)-...$ part I got zero?

Comment: Where did you use the sum to product formula and which one?

Comment: Notice the parity of the $\cos A \cos B$ in the expansion of $\sin(A-B)$. Umm, I think I just derived it in the top line.

Comment: I can't seem to follow. $\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)= \sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B - \sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$. Let $x=\sin A\cos B$ and $y=\cos A\sin B$ then $(x+y)-(x-y)=x+y-x+y=2y=2\cos A\sin B$. Yep, sorry for my utter stupidity at not being able to subtract but yet understand Euler's formula etc. Do you think I should now delete this trivial question due to my quite frankly, stupidity and thus its futility?

Comment: I guess I'll leave it unless others make the same mistake.

Comment: No, not at all. Sorry for the late reply. Your parentheses aren't matched properly. The negative sign on the final $\cos A \sin B$ term should be positive as you're subtracting $\left( \sin A \cos B - \cos A \sin B \right)$ which is the same as adding $-\sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B$.